# Azure Wep App Connection external Cloud SQL

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-web-app-service

I am using Azure Free Subscription. So I can't create a database server. I created a SQL Server on Google Cloud. I want to connect this database with Web App on Azure. How can do this? What should be my connection string? Should I set up a proxy server? Can I use the connection string on Google Cloud like this directly?

connection string

[image: connection string]

Comment: there shouldnt be anything that stops you in connecting. have you actually tried it?

Comment: btw, for 12 months you also get a free SQL Database on Azure: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/free/search/?&ef_id=CjwKCAjwvOHzBRBoEiwA48i6AtNKPed3gTyy-wP29tJATM-qEiwovLuGOxN-wNxUSOiOdM4PCA0PvBoCFGcQAvD_BwE:G:s&OCID=AID2000076_SEM_GScor46O&MarinID=GScor46O_368068002437_%2Bazure%20%2Bfree_b_c__76075621803_kwd-323834433994&lnkd=Google_Azure_Brand&dclid=CJ3At7SZsOgCFRIU4Aod84wMNw#new-products

Comment: free subscription doesn't let create a database server. I asked helpdesk.

Comment: yeah, I was able. thank you all

Comment: able to create a free SQL database after all?

Comment: Not in Azure. Free users don't create a SQL database.